# windows 8 appbar steals focus

Tags: javascript, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I am currently developing an app on Windows 8 using HTML+Javascript.
I am using an iFrame within my app and has added keyeventlisteners for keyboard events.

However, when I right click the mouse the appbar shows up and it steals away the focus of my app so now all the keyboard events are not doing anything. But if right click again to dismiss the appbar everything works fine again.

Does anyone know if the appbar having the focus is by design from Microsoft? Or is it a way to take the focus back to my iFrame?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is intentional; this is so that the user can use whichever method they want to show the App bar, and then use the keyboard to control it. A great way to validate the behavior is to create the default "Grid Template" app in VS, and uncomment the Appbar, adding a few extra buttons, and then test the behavior.

Note, however, that there is a difference in expectation between a *sticky* appbar and a *non-sticky* appbar. In the case of non-sticky, the focus needs to be moved to the app bar, as there is no other way to get to it without causing the app bar to dismiss (when using the keyboard). However, with sticky, which is dismissed only by using the gestures (right click, or win-z, or the swipe on touch), it's ok for focus not to be placed into it by default.

Likely your solution is going to be to attach your even handlers at the document level, rather than in your IFRAME, which will be complicated due to the nature of messaging between the two contexts.